# Is this using the chain rule for this pde - PDE simplification?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following...

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial [p(1-p)]}{\partial x}=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}+(1-p)\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}-p\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=0$

I am wondering if this is due to the chain rule? If not, why does it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the chain rule, it's the Leibniz product rule for derivatives, which says that

$(f(x)g(x))' = f'(x) g(x) + f(x) g'(x), \tag 1$

where I use the abbreviated notation

$h'(x) = \dfrac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x}; \tag 2$

if we now set

$p(x) = f(x), \; 1 - p(x) = g(x), \tag 3$

then we see that

$(p(x)(1 - p(x))' = p'(x)(1 - p(x)) + p(x)(1 - p(x))' = p'(x)(1 - p(x)) - p(x)p'(x). \tag 4$

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really confused by that but now I see it. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: My pleasure sir or ma'am, whichever the case may be, glad to help out! Cheers!